# DecorationImage isn't clipped by BoxDecoration

Tags: dart, flutter

why can't I have a square png image get clipped inside a BoxDecoration parent widget? What have I done wrong?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
final appLogo = Hero(
  tag: 'hero',
  child: Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )),
  ),
);
```

.....

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade100,
  body: Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        appLogo,
        SizedBox(
          height: 48,
        ),
        emailField,
        SizedBox(
          height: 8.0,
        ),
        passwordField,
        SizedBox(
          height: 24.0,
        ),
        loginButton,
        forgotPButton,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using [ClipOval](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue on flutter github about this problem here [Add Container.clipBehavior to clip to the decoration #14421](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14421)

For now you can use a [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) to achive what you want.

Comment: I tried CircleAvatar before and for some reason it also did not clip the square image. That was why I used BoxDecoratin instead...

Comment: Okay, so finally I figured out why the image cannot be clipped. It seems that ListView padding actually stretched the image beyond its container widget.. I manage to get the image clipped by wrapping the appLogo with a Center widget under the ListView layout.. this is very strange and frustrating.

Comment: Just discover this, myself. It's... dumb. I think I understand why it's happening, but it's dumb. And ridiculously unintuitive. :(